# SunOne Webserver HTML Includes

Tags: html, include, server-side-includes, sunone

I'm running a large site, one that has a nav bar at the top. Rather than change the 100+ html files each time we want to change one of the buttons in the top nav, we want to switch the navbar to be displayed using an include of some kind. I want these includes to work on both Firefox and IE, and I don't want to have to change the extensions of each file either.

So far I've tried:

Javascript read file - This works fine on firefox, but IE has file reading blocked it seems.

HTML include - So far only works if we change the extension to shtml

PHP include - I know you can set up apache servers to run php scripts within html, but I don't know how to make this happen in SunOne.

iframes - I had to block iframes in order to comply with security standards.

I'm more than open to suggestions I haven't considered, or ways to make the above attempts work. Any ideas?

Comment: If SSI is indeed an option, I'd seriously consider that. Yes, you will have to change all the extensions, but only once.

Comment: Otherwise, what do the changes consist of? There's a awful lot you can do with CSS.

Comment: The changes consist of changing links. For example, a button will have href="ccsp.html" and src="ccsp.gif", but it needs to be changed to href="weather.html" and scr="weather.gif"

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! I've found it!

So rather than include the html, why not just include the javascript and css? Every page will include a .js and .css file. The css can set the image src, and in each image I can use "onclick" to tell it to execute a function in the .js file with a simple window.location. Voila! Two quick changes will change the whole site!

Thanks to Mr. Lister for the CSS idea. That set me on the path.